# Пустой список компонентов Windows 10, как исправить баг?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Вот, что вижу, когда открываю компоненты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть?

Comment: С этим лучше с техподдержку Microsoft. Даром они что ли таких денег за ОС просят :Р

Comment: @D-side Когда ты начинаешь их этим попрекать, тебя банят на 2 недели :)

Answer (score 4):

Хм... Проблема была замечена ещё в Windows Vista. До сих пор не исправили? Ладно, итак:

1. Заходим в управление службами (можно через Пуск, я предпочитаю Win+R, ввести "services.msc"), ищем там службу "Установщик Windows" (Windows Installer в английской версии). Переводим режим запуска в Автоматический, сохраняем настройки, перезапускаем систему.
2. Если не помогло, запускаем проверку и восстановление системных файлов:

   sfc /SCANNOW

Лучше всего это сделать в Safe Mode, для этого: запускаем msconfig (Win+R, ввести "msconfig"), переходим на вкладку "Загрузка", выбираем безопасный режим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не забываем затем вернуть всё взад, иначе так и будете загружаться в безопасном режиме :)

3. Если не помогло и это, запускаем "мой любимый" DISM:

   Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

Учтите, ждать придётся долго, лучше не прерывать задачи и озаботиться тем, чтобы компьютер был обеспечен бесперебойником.

4. Если ничего не помогло, требуется восстановление или переустановка системы.